# MySQL subquery returns more than one row and inner joins

Tags: mysql, subquery, inner-join

I have the following query:

```
select user_name as rt, 
      (select source_user_name from tweets t where t.rt_user_name = u.user_name)
from topUserData u
```

Now MySQL is giving me an error saying that the subquery returns more than one row. However, what I want here is this one to many relationship. For example if the user_name was james and the subquery returned (Linda, Bob, Suzanna, Sandy, Tom) then I would like the data to be displayed as:

James   Linda

James Bob

James Suzanna

James Sandy

James Tom

How do I get this functionality from what I have? I also see this is similar to an inner join but I want the answer in terms of a subquery. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need `INNER JOIN` in this case

```
SELECT  a.user_name as RT,
        b.source_user_name
FROM    topUserData a
        INNER JOIN tweets b
            ON a.user_name = b.rt_user_name
```

or (*the subquery is not really needed since you didn't have any special actions on the inside*)

```
select user_name as rt, source_user_name 
from topUserData u
     INNER JOIN
     (
         select DISTINCT source_user_name 
         from tweets t 
     ) ON t.rt_user_name = u.user_name
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this is a subquery?

Comment: yes. But i think there is something you want but you don't add it on your question. basically what you are trying to do why you want subquery? `:D`

Comment: Yes, I fixed my question. I do want the solution in terms of a subquery.

Comment: the subquery returns an error because there are many records return by it. anyway, i have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left join

```
select user_name , source_username from topUserData u left join tweets t on t.rt_user_name = u.user_name
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` isn't necessary here.